# How to move an image file from amazon s3 to amazon ec2 and run the instance using java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am a newbie to cloud computing technology and want to move an image file from amazon s3 to amazon ec2 and run it. I will be using JAVA.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

best regards,
Nil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't move an image from S3 to an existing EC2 instance and run it. Instead you can use the Amazon EC2 API to start and stop your instances. See [RunInstances](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/index.html?ApiReference-query-RunInstances.html) or [StartInstances](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-StartInstances.html) in the docs.

You can also perform these functions using the [AWS SDK for Java](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/)

There are a lot of Amazon services available but they are well documented online. You need to give these a good read to understand how they all play together.